# How can I use these boundary conditions to find a solution to this initial value problem to the heat equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation

I am currently trying to solve a heat-equation problem where I am required to solve the PDE
$$
u_t = u_{xx}
$$
subject to the following boundary conditions
$$
u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0, \hspace{20 mm} u(x,0) = \cases{x \hspace{13 mm} \text{ if } \hspace{6 mm} 0<x<\frac{1}{2} \\ 1-x \hspace{5 mm} \text{ if } \hspace{5 mm} \frac{1}{2} < x < 1}.
$$

Assuming that our solution can be expressed in the form $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$, I have deduced (using the first boundary condition) that the only non-trivial solution for $X$ is $X(x) = Be^{\gamma x} \sin(n \pi x)$ where $B$ is a constant to be found, $\gamma$ is arbitrary and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. I have also deduced that the solution for $T$ is of the form $T(t) = e^{\lambda t}$ for some unknown constant $\lambda$.

So, the solution is of the form
$$
u(x,t) = Be^{\gamma x} \sin(n \pi x) \cdot e^{\gamma t}.
$$

I'm now unsure of how to proceed using the second boundary condition. To apply it gives
$$
u(x, 0) = Be^{\gamma x} \sin(n \pi x) = \cases{x \hspace{13 mm} \text{ if } \hspace{6 mm} 0<x<\frac{1}{2} \\ 1-x \hspace{5 mm} \text{ if } \hspace{5 mm} \frac{1}{2} < x < 1}.
$$

But I cannot see how to find the solutions to this system.

Can anyone help me to find a solution to this PDE?

Comment: #1: You want $e^{\gamma t}$, not $e^{\gamma x}$. The dependence of the separable solution on $x$ should just be a sine function, for this type of boundary condition. #2: $\gamma$ should be $\gamma_n$ and can be explicitly calculated (it will turn out to be $-n^2 \pi^2$). #3: In general the solution to a "simple" PDE like this one is *not* separable, but is instead an infinite linear combination of separable solutions. That is, you want to have $u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n e^{-n^2 \pi^2 t} \sin(n \pi x)$ where $B_n$ are chosen so that $u(x,0)$ is the desired initial function.

Comment: The key insight that lets us actually compute $B_n$ (which ordinarily would require us to solve some kind of *infinite linear system*), is that $\sin(n \pi x)$ are orthogonal to each other. Therefore we can compute $B_n$ by just computing an integral.